# Ошибка "Недопустимый неполный тип" при #define

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

я пытаюсь создать шаблон для заполнения, для этого мне требуется запихнуть структуру в структуру. Чтобы не захламлять код я решил написать макро, которое раскрывается в то же самое, но более приглядно выглядит:

Изначальный код: *Test.h*

```
struct Frame
{
    const void* _class;

    struct vftb {
        void(*PrintFrameW)(void* _self, int x, int y, wchar_t character, short color);
        void(*DrawRectangle)(void* self, Word x1, Word y1, Word x2, Word y2, unsigned short color);
    }*meth;


    CHAR_INFO *localFrame;
    WORD nFrameLength;
    WORD nFrameHeight;
};
```

Макро команда(в подключаемом файле):

```
#define mtd(...) struct vftb { __VA_ARGS__ }*meth
```

После применения макро:

```
struct Frame
{
    const void* _class;

    mtd(
        void (*PrintFrameW)(void* _self, int x, int y, wchar_t character, short color);
        void (*DrawRectangle)(void* self, Word x1, Word y1, Word x2, Word y2, unsigned short color);
    );

    CHAR_INFO *localFrame;
    WORD nFrameLength;
    WORD nFrameHeight;
};
```

Однако в Test.c

```
#include "Test.h"

void PrintFrameW(void* _self, int x, int y, wchar_t character, short color);
void DrawRectangle(void* self, Word x1, Word y1, Word x2, Word y2, unsigned short color);

const struct vftb Frame_method = { .PrintFrameW = PrintFrameW, .DrawRectangle = DrawRectangleL }; // Здесь пишет Недопустимый неполный тип. (Объявление в глобальной области)
```

Код при этом компиллируется, но Интеллисенс сходит с ума от таких манипуляций. А еще нужно этот код в макро перевести, для автоматического применения. Как мне устранить эту ошибку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите более-менее полный код а не эти огрызки. По ним совершенно не ясно, что (и где) у вас определено , а что нет. С чего вы взяли, что эта ваша мешанина с макро "не захламляет код" и "более приглядно выглядит" - мне не ясно.

Comment: *Чтобы не захламлять код я решил написать макро, которое раскрывается в то же самое, но более приглядно выглядит* - это только прячет суть происходящего. Оно, конечно, с опытом придет понимание, что писать нужно понятно, но лучше начинайте прямо сейчас :)

Comment: @Harry не совсем правильно выразился, макро мне для автоматизации процесса, они делают мне названия структуры, а второе их предназначение, чтобы код типа Byte __internal_prtb[ sizeof( struct _private{ __VA_ARGS__ } )]
превращать в privatev(...)

Answer (score 1):

`struct vtfb` будет полным типом только если он предварительно определен. У вас этот тип не определен.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91756/discussion-between-ilya-pakhmutov-and-ant).